# Convergence rate to the average value for a sequence that is uniformly distributed modulo $1$

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, summation, asymptotics, uniform-distribution

Let $x_n$ be a sequence of real numbers that asymptotically follow a uniform distribution modulo $1$ (for example, $x_n=n\sqrt{2}$ with $n$ positive integer $\leq N$ and  $N\rightarrow \infty$). It is well known that the average value of $\{x_n\}$, calculated for all  $n \leq N$, tends to $1/2$ as $N\rightarrow \infty$. Similarly, the average value of $\{x_n\}^2$ tends to $1/3$. The convergence to this value is often described by a probabilistic approach (e.g. citing the central limit theorem, the progressive tendency to the standard normal CDF, and so on).

I am interested in describing this convergence rate  using a Big-$O$ notation, to point out its asymptotic behaviour in more direct way. In particular, writing

$$\frac1N \sum_{1\leq n\leq N} \{x_n\}= \frac{1}{2}+R(N)$$

and

$$\frac1N \sum_{1\leq n\leq N} \{x_n\}^2= \frac{1}{3}+S(N)$$

I would like to know the magnitude of the error terms $R(N)$ and $S(N)$ as $N \rightarrow \infty$. By taking into account the CLT, the properties of the [Irwin-Hall distribution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution) and the [Berry–Esseen theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry%E2%80%93Esseen_theorem), it seems that both errors have magnitude $O(N^{-1})$. However, I would be happy to obtain a formal proof of this.

Comment: The natural guess is that these are the same as if the sequence of $x_n$ actually were iid uniform on $[0,1]$. Do you know the bounds then?

Comment: Yes, this is the simplest guess. However, the problem is not to know the resulting probability distribution, but to express it in an asymptotic form by a formal proof.

Comment: Does $\{x_n\}$ following uniform distribution means for every interval $I$, $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{|I \cap \{1,2,\cdots n\}|}{n}=m(I)$? ($m(I)$ is the length of $I$) If so, I think there need not exist a magnitude for error terms, at least for $R$.

Comment: See my answer at MO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/221407/distribution-of-the-error-term-in-gh-hardys-curious-result-sum-nu-leq-n/272402#272402